# Django 1.7 app registry: defining blank/required based on DB query

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I have a database field in which I want the `required` value to be dependent on some setting stored in the database. As a simple example:

```
class ModelSetting(models.Model):
    key=models.CharField(unique=True)
    value=models.BooleanField()

def get_setting(key):
    return ModelSetting.objects.get(key=key).value

class MyModel(models.Model):
    phone_number=models.CharField(required=get_setting("phone_required"))
```

The problem is that `ModelSetting` is defined in a completely different module from `MyModel`, so I guess at import time (when the `phone_number` field is evaluated) the `ModelSetting` model isn't available for use. Is this the case? And is there a possible workaround for it?

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`required` isn't a valid option for `models.CharField`, you probably want to set `blank` instead.

Are you sure that you want your models to depend on settings in the database? That means that Django will prompt to do migrations when the model settings change.

Another approach would be to set `blank=True` in your model field, then check the `phone_required` setting in your forms. This way, you should be able to avoid `AppRegistryNotReady` errors.

Comment: Ah, I actually meant `blank`. Is it true that Django will prompt for migrations when the settings DB changes? When I was on 1.6 this wasn't the case.

Comment: Also, some of my fields use a similar technique for `default`. Would it be sufficient to check for required/blank fields and fill the default in the model's `clean` method?

Comment: Django 1.6 doesn't have migrations at all, so you can't really compare the behaviour to 1.7. I'm pretty sure that if you change `blank` or `default` in Django 1.7, then it will prompt to create a migration.

Comment: It might be better to override the model's `save` rather than `clean` -- model validation will not always be run before the model is saved.

Comment: I was using South before and that didn't require migrations to change the values, but I'll try putting the logic in the `save` method anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about South. You're right, South doesn't require migrations for changes to `blank` or `default`, but Django in 1.7+ does.